# How to configure confluent kafka with azur SQL with CDC approach?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, cdc, confluent-platform

The main thing is i want to connect Azur SQL to confluent kafka using CDC approach and then i want to take that data into s3.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of getting data out of a database into Kafka. You'll need to check what Azure SQL supports but [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos) ([slides](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc)) goes into the options and examples, usually built using Kafka Connect.

To stream data to S3 from Kafka use Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka), using the [S3 sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3) which is detailed in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once).

To see an example of database-S3 pipelines with transformations included have a look at [this blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/).